WebRTC connection could not be established on Chrome 124
i am working on an application that uses webrtc connections for audio, while testing the new version of chrome 124, which is currently in beta but to be released officially in a few days, we noticed that the audio stopped working for us.
while listening for packets using wireshark that are sent between the client and the server we noticed that one packet that informs us handshake when trying to initialize the connection, but it is not written what caused this error

looking further we extended the webrtc logs in chrome with additional flags --enable-logging --vmodule=/webrtc/=1
from them we were able to read additional information that informs us that the error occurred when the client tried to send the certificate [18496:21896:0403/131717.236:WARNING:openssl_adapter.cc(820)] write_alert fatal handshake failure TLS client send_client_certificate [18496:21896:0403/131717.236:INFO:openssl_adapter.cc(817)] connect_exit TLS client send_client_certificate [18496:21896:0403/131717.236:WARNING:openssl_stream_adapter.cc(949)] OpenSSLStreamAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, 1, 0) [18496:21896:0403/131717.236:INFO:dtls_transport.cc(756)] DtlsTransport[0|1|]: DTLS transport error, code=1 [18496:21896:0403/131717.236:VERBOSE1:dtls_transport.cc(863)] DtlsTransport[0|1|]: set_dtls_state from:1 to 4
RTCPeerConnection went into failed state on onconnectionstatechange listener
Application is working fine on all older versions of chromium and all Firefox versions
What could have caused this error in the new version? Looking through the changes in the changelog, I did not find anything that could cause this error https://chromestatus.com/features#milestone%3D124

Chromium developers might be able help you: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev

filing a bug with the WebRTC component and using bisect-builds.py https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py/ to identify the commit that caused a change in behavior. You will need to include a little more detail about the other  side of the connection

Did you post in Groups? I posted here: https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/0RYZwT8eWWM/m/lb2Uop6nAAAJ Are you using SIPSorcery?

The issue for us was we only supported ClientCertificateType.rsa_sign but needed to support ClientCertificateType.ecdsa_sign for Chrome 124 as well.

that was the same case for us
